# Wordpress add property to page

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to add some kind of "properties" to a Wordpress page? In the admin interface i would like to have a couple of different properties that the page should have to choose from, and then i can "pick up" the value of those properties in my template. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WordPress pages have custom meta values, which can be retrieved in the theme.

In the page editor, you can add meta values by pulling down the "Screen Options" menu at the top-right of the page and checking "Custom Fields". If you do that, a box will show up below the post editor where you can enter custom fields.

You can read more about custom fields (including how to retrieve them from your theme) on the WordPress.org Custom Field documentation page.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

For example, if you store a "weather" field, you can get it in the theme with something like the following:

```
<?php
global $post;
echo "Weather: " . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'weather', true);
?>
```